# Too many requests from this IP address

Tags: support, stack-exchange, api, stackexchange-2.0, throttling

I am using the StackAPI library for Python to access Stack Overflow questions. I need to collect all question IDs attached with a particular tag (for example, regex).

I used the search bar on Stack Overflow with the query `[regex]`. The Stack Overflow search engine indicated that there are 725,098 questions.

With StackAPI, I set the `page_size` to 100 and `max_pages` to 7251. Since I have an API key, my quota is 10000 per day. When I run the code, it throws an error code for throttle violation. I am not sure why.

Note: I am using a custom filter with *back_off* checked.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange API Optimal, Acceptable Request Frequency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349227/295232)

Comment: Did you obey the `throttle`? Note: even if you obey the `throttle` you need to handle all other types of  responses from the SE API, as the responses which the SE API give are undefined under common circumstances (e.g. when your IP is temporarily blocked/throttled, which is related to but separate from a `throttle` response).

Comment: Since I had the `remaining_quota` over 9000, setting the `max_pages` to less than should technically obey the throttle. Unless I didn't account for anything else on top of the number of pages.

Comment: What do you do if you receive a value in backoff? How many calls do you make per 90 seconds?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any option in the library to deal with backoff? So, I went old school and used the requests module in Python and manually add a sleep time for 2 secs between each page request. I go to a new iteration to access the next page in a loop if `has_more` is true and `remaining_quota` is over 100

Comment: Unless you need it in realtime or up to date, I wonder if the datadumps or SEDE might be a better option...

Comment: Using the data dump was my only option.